# hide only this part of datatable (filtered from x total entries)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatables

i want to show only this content of data table Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries but want to hide later part of it (filtered from x total entries)how is it possible help me

Comment: You can do that by changing [language option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language) of datatable.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can acheive this by specifying `empty string` for `infoFiltered` in [Language configuration options for DataTables](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "language": {                
            "infoFiltered": ""
        }
    } );
} );
```

Pleasee see this [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/5q9ov545/) for demostration.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it is working fine

Answer (score -1):

In the core file (jquery.dataTables.js), search for a string "(filtered from *MAX* total entries)" and make it empty.

Comment: It is not recommended to change core JS files.

Comment: i am working on rails project and using following gem for it gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'

Comment: i have search those are some solution "language": {
    "infoFiltered": " - filtered from _MAX_ records"
  } another is $('#example').dataTable( {
  "language": {
    "infoPostFix": "All records shown are derived from real information."
  }
} );
but i not getting how it will apply